# SQL Server on Linux caps the memorylimitmb setting

Tags: sql-server, linux

I have a 64GiB Ubuntu machine with SQL Server 2017 installed. Setting [`memory.memorylimitmb`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-configure-mssql-conf?view=sql-server-ver15#memorylimit) to anything higher than 63695 megabytes is ignored. Setting it to 67000 megabytes (which is 62.3 GiB roughly) still results in SSMS reporting 63695 MB available (right-click server, properties - general - memory row). Lower settings are reflected there just fine.

This results in SQL Server not using all available memory, it only uses 59.2, leaving more than 4 gigs empty.

Again, this is my "mssql.conf":

```
[memory]
memorylimitmb = 67000
```

But this is how much memory is reported by SSMS:

[image]

(note: this is NOT the "max memory" setting, this is where SSMS simply says how much memory is installed on the machine, under "Server - Properties - General - Memory")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the way Linux is showing the available memory. For example, take the follow Azure virtual machine:

> Standard D4s v3 (4 vcpus, 16 GiB memory)

> 20.04.1-Ubuntu

If you look at what the reported memory available is for the server (using the above as the example server), you'll see the reported amount of 16010. All SQL Server is doing is reporting what the OS says, in this case even if you change the value to a much larger number (above 16 GB) there isn't anything SQL Server can do as that's not what the OS is reporting (.

> MiB Mem :  16010.9 total

SQL Server calls into the OS to ask it what it sees and thus is only mirroring what it is shown (when the value for `memorylimitmb` is set equal to the server memory). Note that you're seeing this in SSMS which is just taking the value from SQL Server DMVs.

> Detected 16010 MB of RAM. This is an informational message; no user action is required.

Comment: Which command did you use to get the "16010" response? Because the `htop` command on my Linux reports "62.5GB" total, of which only "59.3 GB" is used by SQL Server. And 59.3 is exactly 63695 megabytes - the magic number SQL limits itself with. Are you bascially saying that's all because of the "giBibyte/giGabyte" confusion and miscalculation between different apps?

Comment: @jitbit I used `top` and there is no way we can control the way other programs show information. SQL Server sees exactly what the OS reports - though it's slightly shadowed by the fact that there is a translation layer for the OS call - it's still a call to the OS to get available memory. For example, one output is rounded down or doesn't use fractions, one is not rounded at all (16010 vs 16010.9).

Comment: My experience is that SQL Server (SSMS) shows what's set up by the "memorylimitmb" setting. Tweaking that setting and restarting SQL updates that number (the one on the screenshot)

Comment: @jitbit That's not how it works, SSMS queries the DMV in SQL Server, which reads from the configuration and also queries the OS for its information. You can't set memory to more than what you have. You're thinking that there should be 67000 MB, the OS is telling you that you have 63695. You can't push it past that, it's not a SQL thing it's an OS thing. Period.

Comment: Yes, I understand I can't push it above the actual RAM (but pushing below works tho). What I'm trying to understand, why is the OS telling SQL the wrong number ("63695" is only "59.3 GiB", right?). However, using `free` (not `htop`) gives me other values, reporting only 500MB of free memory (htop shows 3 GBs). So, I guess it's some kind of inconsistent conversion between GB and GiB (i.e. basing on 1000 vs. 1024) *within* htop...